# Посмотреть актуальный TTL

Tags: macos

Везде пишут про обход блокировок с помощью изменения `TTL`. И есть нужные команды, но нигде не пишут, как посмотреть актуальный `TTL` на `Mac OS`. Может вы знаете команду `Terminal`, чтобы посмотреть текущее значение `TTL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прочитать параметр:

```
sudo sysctl -n net.inet.ip.ttl
```

Записать параметр:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.ttl=65
```

[Документация по sysctl](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sysctl.8.html).

Answer (score 0):

Например можно посмотреть через командную строку (в винде) или терминал (в маке) как

> ping 127.0.0.1

Покажет ТТЛ первого пакета, он же будет актуальным ттл